# Quelle phrase citée dans les détails est la mieux construite?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Quelle phrase a la meilleure structure? Sont-elles toutes correctes? De quelle façon auriez-vous exprimé cette idée? Mon hésitation porte surtout sur les deuxième et troisième énonciations avec « comme » et « pour », qui s’entendraient mais qui ne donnent pas l’impression d’être naturelles ou coulantes, sinon qui ne paraissent pas appartenir à un registre élevé de la langue française. S’il n’en tenait qu’à moi, je dirais que la dernière possède la meilleure architecture. À partir de maintenant je m’en remets à votre jugement.

> **Cela a sans doute été une première nuit en dehors de chez elle (dans une résidence) pénible** à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

> **Cela a dû être pénible comme première nuit en dehors de chez elle** (dans une résidence) à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

> **Cela a dû être pénible pour une première nuit en dehors de chez elle** (dans une résidence) à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence

> **Cette première nuit en dehors de chez elle a sans doute été pénible** à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/

> Cela a sans doute été une première nuit en dehors de chez elle (dans une résidence) pénible à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

La modification « pénible à cause de … » est difficilement associée à « nuit » ; la lecture ne se fait pas bien facilement parce  qu'il y a une parenthèse qui  brise la continuité. De plus, une virgule est nécessaire après  la parenthèse parce que le syntagme adjectival de noyau « pénible » ne peut modifier « nuit » que sur la base d'une apposition lorsque séparé du nom par certains élément. Il y a parfois le choix d'une apposition ([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-59568.php)).
Indépendamment de cette nécessité, même si la parenthèse est omise, une apposition qui suit le nom n'est plus ou moins sûre du point de vue syntaxe que si elle se trouve directement après ; dans les autres cas la lecture peut être floue, donc l'apposition indésirable. Lapposition d'adjectifs n'est pas une chose simple.

- Cela a sans doute été une première nuit en dehors de chez elle (dans une résidence), pénible à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence. (*pas recommendé*)
- Cela a sans doute été une première nuit en dehors de chez elle, pénible à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.
- <s>Cela a sans doute été une première nuit en dehors de chez elle, pénible.</s>
- <s>Cela a sans doute été une première nuit, pénible.</s>
- Cela a sans doute été une première nuit pénible. (*la construction avec l'adjectif en épithéte est cependant parfaite.*)

Elle est possible lorsque séparée du nom par certaines constructions mais pas d'autres, ou lorsque l'adjectif est lui-même modifié.

- Elle avait passé une première nuit sans problèmes, pénible seulement parce qu'elle avait été longue.
- <s>Elle avait passé une première nuit sans problèmes, paisible.</s>

Le sujet mérite un traitement beaucoup plus extensif, mais il faudra s'en tenir aux quelques principes introduits par les exemples qui viennent d'être donnés en se rappelant que c'est un sujet complexe.

2/

> Cela a dû être pénible comme première nuit en dehors de chez elle (dans une résidence) à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

« Comme » ne pourrait signifier que « en tant que »,  « en qualité de », il n'y a pas d'autre possibilité.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme)) En qualité de ; en tant que.
>
> ♦ L'acide arsénieux est un des poisons les plus violents; il agit comme tel sur toutes les classes des animaux et sur les plantes.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme))
> **II.− Morph. de compar. Dans ces emplois** ***comme*** **exprime une idée de similitude, l'écart avec l'idée d'identité pouvant être plus ou moins réduit selon le contexte.**
> **Rem. 1**  **Cette tournure plus ou moins relâchée apparaît fréquemment dans la lang. pop.**
> ♦  Notez qu'avec les femmes on travaille, mais qu'est-ce qu'on prend comme ennuis, pour un oui ou pour un non, la police fourrage dans vos papiers. E. Dabit, L'Hôtel du Nord,1929, p. 13.
> ♦  Son bled c'est à vingt minutes de chez moi une fois qu'on a passé la Seine. Il faisait pas joli comme temps. Céline, Mort à crédit,1936, p. 13.

Remplacer « comme » par « en tant que » dans cette construction  n'est cependant pas satisfaisant ; l'idée ne correspond pas bien, et donc c'est une tournure a bannir d'un langage qui se veut précis.

3/

> Cela a dû être pénible pour une première nuit en dehors de chez elle (dans une résidence) à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour))
> **I.− [Marque l'idée d'échange ou de substitution, celle d'équivalence, d'où p. ext. celle de simple repérage]**
> **B.− [Rapport d'équivalence]**
> **Comme, en fait de, en guise de, en tant que**
> ♦ Au-dessus de la muraille, vous verrez, pour inscriptions, des têtes de morts entassés dans des cages de fer (Quinet, All. et Ital.,1836, p. 178)
> ♦ ... un important groupement, constitué à l'avance dans la région de Sontay sous les ordres du général Alessandri, avec, pour noyau, la Légion, remplit vaillamment sa mission. De Gaulle, Mém. guerre,1959, p. 166.

On retrouve dans ce « pour » le mot examiné précédemment, « comme », et aussi « en tant que », les deux comme synonymes.  Il reste le synonyme  « en fait de », qui signifie « en ce qui concerne ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fait))
> **C.− Ce dont il est question ou ce dont on parle (chose, sujet, cas, affaire particulière).**
> **5. En fait de, loc. prép. En ce qui concerne, en matière de.**

Cependant, « cela est X en ce qui concerne une première nuit » ne communique pas une idée qui corresponde à la réalité : il n'existe très probablement pas de première nuit type dans le contexte, pas de considérations particulières que l'on puisse avoir pour cette nuit-là, c'est juste la première nuit ; de plus « cela » ne représente apparemment pas  des évènements donnés au cours de la première nuit mais par le biais de ce que « pour » insinue le plus fortement c'est la  première nuit elle-même, et on en revient à l'idée de catégorisation par le biais de « comme ». « Cela » n'est pas un présentatif et doit donc remplacer une description que l'on peut nommer comme étant celle d'une nuit, et ceci est assez improbable. Il semblerait que dans ce troisième cas on fait face à une indéfinition de la relation que le mot « pour » est sensé introduire.

4/

> Cette première nuit en dehors de chez elle a sans doute été pénible à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence.

Cette quatrième formulation n'offre pas de difficulté et résoud le problème de la possibilité que « cela » serait insinué en présentatif  dans les trois premières phrases, ou à défaut de celle d'un remplacement pour une caractérisation peu probable  d'une nuit ; la locution prépositionnelle « à cause de » est maintenant placée directement après le constituant auquel elle est reliée (pénible) et la lecture se fait bien. Cette apparition de « sans doute » dans cette quatrième version est cependant un problème : voici ce que le TLFi en dit (**Remarque**).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doute)) **D.− Loc. adv. Sans doute**
> **1.** [À valeur affirmative] Vieilli. Assurément, certainement. C'est là sans doute une très belle action (Ac.1835-1932).Sans doute la richesse est une très-grande puissance (Destutt de Tr., Comment. sur Espr. des lois,1807, p. 172).
> **Rem.** Cette valeur de sans doute s'est atténuée au point que, pour exprimer l'affirmation, on renforce le subst. par aucun, nul, On préférera sans nul doute la première version (Huyghe, Dialog. avec visible, 1955, p. 213). Fainéant, prodigue, coureur, ivrogne, menteur − et j'en passe − Jacques était sans aucun doute un détestable mari (Beauvoir, Mém. j. fille, 1958, p. 346).
> **2.** [À valeur dubitative définitive ou provisoire] Probablement, certes, je vous l'accorde. Vous avez sans doute raison; il vous arrive sans doute de
> ♦ le prince paul. − Enfin, nous sommes donc unis! ... nous sommes donc l'un à l'autre! ... la grande duchesse, légèrement. − Sans doute... sans doute... Meilhac, Halévy, La Grande duchesse de Gérolstein,1867, IV, 2, p. 295.
> − [Avec dans la prop. suivante un mot comme mais corrigeant − en la limitant − l'extension du doute] Maman (...) trouva même (...) certaine maison décente, sans doute étroite de pignon, sans doute privée de jardin, mais bonne pour un docteur (Duhamel, Terre promise,1934, p. 71).

Il vaut donc mieux l'éviter et se rabattre sur des termes tels « peut-être » et « sans le moindre doute »,  « sans aucun doute », etc.

Il y a cependant deux nuances.

- Cette première nuit en dehors de chez elle a sans aucun doute été pénible à cause de tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence. (*On sait par avance que la nuit a été pénible et on déduit la cause.*)
- Cette première nuit en dehors de chez elle a sans aucun doute été pénible si on en juge par tous ces hurlements de terreur poussés par des vieux atteints de toutes sortes de démence. (*On ne sait pas par avance que la nuit a été pénible mais on le suppose au vu de certaines conditions qui ne peuvent qu'être la cause d'une nuit pénible.*)

Il faut se rendre compte que la seconde énonciation ne peut pas être paraphrasée par la première ; une telle ambigüité n'existe pas, à mon avis. Je précise ce fait parce qu'on n'est pas certain de quelle nuance il s'agit dans « 1/ », que dans « 2/ » on tend fortement à croire qu'il s'agit de la nuance « 2 » puisque « devoir » peut s'interprèter comme exprimant la possibilité (d'être pénible) ;  dans « 3/ », c'est pareil.